# & converted into "&amp;"

Tags: migration, content-migration

Recently we have migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I notice now that data in some columns where an `"&"` is present is changed into  `"&amp;"`. The same is true for `"` which gets converted to `&quot;`.

List data doesn't seem to render properly anymore.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: is the list custom? looks like HtmlEncode is happing on the list items!

Comment: The list is custom indeed. A PowerShell script was used to migrate the content.

Comment: Is this an option on column level? I don't think so. How can this be turned off then?